# Firefox Not Loading - selenium webdriver programming

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I was trying to run python + selenium on a virtual machine of XP (using VirtualBox), this way all the testing work can always run in the background. But the problem i'm facing right now is that when it comes to `browser.get("http://google.com")`, it does NOT load at all. Anybody could help me out?

**Update:** Sorry guys, I'm using selenium 2.22 all the time in order to keep consistent on both sides, but I easy_installed selenium 2.2 by mistake... Anyway problem solved.

Comment: can you paste some more code.. how are u assigning `browser` to webdriver.Firefox()

Comment: I had similar problems with chromedriver. Downloading the latest version seemed to solve the problem.